# Appending to lists, with variables. Python

Tags: python

I have made a math quiz(simple.asks 10 maths question to the user). I made the user take the quiz 3 times using a for loop, because i needed 3 scores for each student.I decided to store the 3 scores in a list HOWEVER because the variable "score" changes every time the for loop runs and every time the user does the quiz..i find it very difficult to append each score in the same list one after another.

I have read some other response to a similar question and the answer was the use of indexes, but i am not quiet sure how i could use them for my problem as i don't have a specific location in the list to add my 3 different scores, i need to add them one after another.

Here is the part in my code  that i need to work on:

```
 hscore = []
    hscore.append(score)
    print("This is hscore: ",hscore)


    score = 0
```

I am sorry, this is my first time using this webiste so..i don't know how to present my code properly. But as you can see..i have my empty list which i want to append to. score is the variable that changes 3 times, and the print was just for me to check if it was working which it wasn't. Also every time the for loops runs again i had to set the score to 0, so the scores wouldn't get add up together.

Comment: This will also need some work before it succeeds on Stack Overflow. You need to explain *if it was working which it wasn't* why it isn't working, and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I agree with @Compass. Please also consider adding a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Anyways, StephRus, please go through [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make any changes you can to improve your question.

Comment: Please show the `for` loop, too.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare all variables out side your loop, cause it looks like you're resetting score to 0.
And as a recommendation, try using a dictionary to better handle this kind of information.
Like this:

```
scores={}
scores[Name]=[]
## Your code block here
## or for loop
    scores[Name].append(score)
print scores[Name]
```

scores will be able to hold the scores of each student with a list of their score. Hope that helps! :)